# Is it possible to take input variables in shell?

Tags: shell

For example, if I ran:

```
$ sh somescript inputvariable
```

if so, how would I use this variable in the script?

For example

```
$ sh somescript 7
```

Comment: What is "`inputvariable`"? Can you give more detail about what you expect? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: a variable I could use in the script